# how to fix unordered "fetch" in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am fetching multiple route using for loop and saving its result
this is my code

```
 for (let i = 0; i < datesToFetch.length; i++) {


fetch("http://localhost:3000/areaChart/"+datesToFetch[i]+"/"+datesToFetch[i+1])
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))

}
```

whats really weird that order of data that I am getting is coming random order it is not coming according to for loop ascending order which is really important in this case

what should I do so I get data in proper order  ?

Comment: You're getting a random order because the sources take different amount of time to load and deliver. You either can can save the response in an Array and then sort it, when all is loaded or use promises or whatever... hard to tell without knowing what you fetch.

Comment: You should have a look at `Promise.all`, this would help you with that task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's going on, and how to fix it:

Your code is queueing up a bunch of `fetch`es, but not waiting for them to finish before moving on to the next iteration of the loop. They can finish in any order.

If instead you wanted the loop to stop and wait each time, wrap it in an `async` function, and `await` the fetch.

```
async function test() {

    for (let i = 0; i < datesToFetch.length; i++) {
        var response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/areaChart/"+datesToFetch[i]+"/"+datesToFetch[i+1]);
        var responseJson = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJson);
    }

}
```

---

#### A simulation of your code:

```js
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

async function test() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(`Starting call #${i}`);
    delay(5000 - (i * 1000))
      .then(() => console.log(`Call #${i} has completed.`));
  }
}

test();
```

#### A simulation of the solution provided above:

```js
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

async function test() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(`Starting call #${i}`);
    await delay(5000 - (i * 1000));
    console.log(`Call #${i} has completed.`);
  }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to asynchronous code!

One thing you can do is create an empty array that is `datesToFetch.length` long, and assign the value of `response.json()` to the appropriate index.

```
const responses = [...Array(datesToFetch.length)]

for (let i = 0; i < datesToFetch.length; i++) {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/areaChart/"+datesToFetch[i]+"/"+datesToFetch[i])
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => responses[i] = response)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your case :

You are calling multiple functions that have different resolution time. It's like behing at mcDonald in different queues, some gyus arrived at the same time as you could get his meal before or after yourself.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function display(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(i);
    }, getRandomInt(1500));
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  display(i)
    .then(x => console.log('->', x));
}
```

---

One soluce :

We are using a function called `Promise.all` to wait for all people to get theirs meals, and then go out of the shop.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function display(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(i);
    }, getRandomInt(1500));
  });
}

const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  promises.push(display(i));
}

// We use Promise.all to wait for all responses
// The responses are in the call order
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((rets) => {
      rets.forEach(x => console.log('->', x));
  });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the `getRandomInt` function?

Comment: @Jim It's just an example async function like `fetch`, but actually works in the snippet

Answer (score 1):

That's because this fetch call will be added to the JavaScript event loop. The first one which gives back result will be displayed, so the order can be different then the order in which they are called.

To fix this you should take a look at the await operator.
More info can be found here: https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait